# What is difference between startingOffsets earliest and startingOffsets latest in spark streaming job when streaming source is kafka?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to read stream from kafka using spark streaming job . There is property startingoffsets which value either can be earliest or latest. I am confused with startingoffsets when it is set to latest.

My assumption when startingoffsets  is set earliest it reads data from beginning and when latest it reads data from kafka after the start time of spark streaming job or that of query execution time . However when it is earliest it is working as expected but when I set latest and run streaming application it does not read any data from kafka .

Comment: streaming or stuctured streaming?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_auto.offset.reset), the property specifies what to do when there is no consumer offset on the server.

> What to do when there is no initial offset in Kafka or if the current offset does not exist any more on the server (e.g. because that data has been deleted):

The `earliest` will read the data in the topic from the beginning. You say that it works as expected, and that `latest` does not. With `latest`, you have to push data after you started reading.

Comment: that's issue , my understanding with latest is same , when set latest data that is pushed after stream started should only be read , but it is not happening .

Comment: Their [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html) is the same. Maybe there is something wrong on your end.